# how to put slider in an image?

Tags: html, css, slider, containers, bxslider

I would like to put slider(bxslider) in an image. Slider itself contains content(small image and text). I am trying to put the slider by setting:

```
position:relative; //to main image container
position absolute; // to Slider container
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Here is visual representation.

[image]

Comment: you need post your code, then we will help you

Comment: have you tried making the main image a background image?